# Call external fetch function in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have outsourced a fetch function into **lib/cityData.js**

```
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';

const fetchCityData = (city) => {  
  const options = {
    method: `POST`,
  };
  fetch(`${server}/api/weather?city=${city}`, options)
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.ok){
      return response.json().then(data => console.log(data))
      
    }
      throw new Error('Api is not available') 
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data in city data: ', error)
  })
}
//fetchCityData('London')
module.exports.fetchCityData = fetchCityData;
```

Data is an object, so fetchCityData('London') returns

```
{
  location: {
    name: 'London',
    region: 'City of London, Greater London',
    country: 'United Kingdom',
    lat: 51.52,
    lon: -0.11,
    tz_id: 'Europe/London',
    localtime_epoch: 1632394483,
    localtime: '2021-09-23 11:54'
  },
  current: {
    last_updated_epoch: 1632393900,
    last_updated: '2021-09-23 11:45',
    temp_c: 18,
    temp_f: 64.4,
    is_day: 1,
    condition: {
      text: 'Partly cloudy',
      icon: '//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png',
      code: 1003
    },
    wind_mph: 13.6,
    wind_kph: 22,
    wind_degree: 250,
    wind_dir: 'WSW',
    pressure_mb: 1020,
    pressure_in: 30.12,
    precip_mm: 0,
    precip_in: 0,
    humidity: 73,
    cloud: 75,
    feelslike_c: 18,
    feelslike_f: 64.4,
    vis_km: 10,
    vis_miles: 6,
    uv: 4,
    gust_mph: 11.2,
    gust_kph: 18
  }
}
```

So, now I have a component and this needs this data. The process is as follows

1. In input user types city
2. Auto select gets fired
3. onSelect city is set (`setCity(city)`)

This happens in the component **SearchBar.js.** Then city is being passed to the component **ForecastButtons.js**

This component takes the city and then onClick it should call my function above fetchCityData.js and return current temperature for the selected city. Before my fetchCityData function was part of **ForecastButtons** component, but I needed to outsource it, so now, of course the code is broken:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import fetchCityData from '../lib/cityData'

export const ForecastButtons = ({ city }) => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
  const location = payload?.location?.name;
  const currentTemp = payload?.current?.temp_c;

  return(
    <div className="sm:col-span-2">
      <p className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Select forecast</p>
        <button onClick={fetchCityData} className="mt-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded" type='button'>
          Today
        </button>
        <p key={city?.location?.id} className='my-5'>
          { location ? `Current weather in ${location} is ${currentTemp} degrees ` : 'Please search for city to see current weather'}
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

setPayload in this component was called after fetch returned json. Now the payload is basically my data. Should I import the function somehow and setPayload(data)? I am new to react, this is way to complex for me. How do I use fetchCityData, setPayload and onClick in the button of my component still get the weather?

Comment: You can convert `fetchCityData` to hook, which will return [data, error, loading]. In this case you should add `useState` and `useEffect` to  `fetchCityData`

Comment: useState and useEffect can be only be used in components. fetchCityData is not a component.

Comment: This is why I wrote that `You can convert fetchCityData to hook`. Only than you can do that

Comment: Is this the only way to solve it? It's is a whole lot of a task for e beginner :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would simply be:

**cityData.js**

```
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';

const fetchCityData = (city) => {  
  const options = {
    method: `POST`,
  };
  return fetch(`${server}/api/weather?city=${city}`, options)
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.ok){
      return response.json()
    }
      throw new Error('Api is not available') 
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data in city data: ', error)
  })
}
```

**ForecasButtons.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchCityData } from '../lib/cityData'

export const ForecastButtons = ({ city }) => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null)

  const getData = () => {
    fetchCityData(city).then((payload) => setPayload(payload));
  }
  const location = payload?.location?.name;
  const currentTemp = payload?.current?.temp_c;

  return(
    <div className="sm:col-span-2">
      <p className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Select forecast</p>
        <button onClick={getData} className="mt-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded" type='button'>
          Today
        </button>
        <p key={city?.location?.id} className='my-5'>
          { location ? `Current weather in ${location} is ${currentTemp} degrees ` : 'Please search for city to see current weather'}
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It works, but as a beginner, I can't tell if this solution has any downsides.

Answer (score 0):

So I did just quick sketch how it could be. As I sad I transformed fetchCityData  to hook `usefetchCityData` which return [data, loading, error]. We call that hook providing `city`. Inside hook when `city` changing `useEffect` calls server, updates all states, and returns [data, loading, error]. I am using my fake data and timeout to imitate network connection, also you can get fake error from server.

hooks.js:

```
// import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

const useFetchCityData = (city) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
    const server = dev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://your_deployment.server.com";

    setData(undefined);
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);

    const options = {
      method: `POST`,
    };

    // axios(`${server}/api/weather?city=${city}`, options)
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() > 0.2) {
          resolve(`data from server for ${city}`);
        }
        reject();
      }, 2000);
    })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data in city data: ", error);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
      });
  }, [city]);

  return [data, loading, error];
};

export { useFetchCityData };
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFetchCityData } from "./hooks";

const App = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState("London");

  const [data, loading, error] = useFetchCityData(city);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>data: {data}</div>
      <div>loading: {loading.toString()}</div>
      <div>error: {error.toString()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```